# Standard normal variable median and quantile.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

$y$ is standard normal random variable and  $x=|y|$.

1. What will be the median of $x$?
2. $P (1 < x < 2)$?
3. $0.80$ quantile of $x$?

Comment: i am completely blank in a

Comment: (a) median approx .67; (c) 80th percentile approx 1.28;  (b) 0.2718 from normal tables. Use hint of @stud_iisc.

Comment: You seem to be simultaneously 'outsourcing' three fairly basic hwk problems. I fear that will soon lead to disaster in your course. Fine to work problems and check answers here. Sometimes even to get a nudge in the right direction, but cannot stay in 'completely blank' mode for long and survive.  I've been teaching this stuff for almost 50 yrs and I don't see any good coming of this for you personally. Please read the chapter before you start hwk; don't just hope  the right formula will magically jump off the page to rescue you. Almost never happens. And then there's exam time. Aargh!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. You have to find $u$ such that $P(-\infty < x < u) = 0.5$. Here $u$ is the median of $x$.
2. $P (1 < x < 2) = P(-1<y<-2) + P(1<y<2).$
3. You have to find $v$ such that $P(-\infty < x < v) = 0.8$. Here $v$ is the $0.8$-quantile of $x$.

More hints as requested by @ernie:

1. $P(-\infty < x < u) = P(-\infty<y<u) + P(u<y<\infty) =2*P(u<y<\infty) = 0.5.$
2. Replace $u$ by $v$ and $0.5$ by $0.8$ in above.

Given $y \sim N(0,1)$, the above hints must be sufficient to find the end results.

Comment: Added more hints in the answer @ernie.

Comment: is the answer of a 0.674

Comment: The median is ~0.674, yes. I was of some help. :)